# AngularJS ng-repeat: Dynamically render/bind canvas inside loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas, angularjs-directive

Relatively new to the world of AngularJS, enjoying it so far.
However, I'm struggling with my attempt to loop through entries in my db and render a `<canvas>` for each one.

Say this is my data (shortened for brevity):

```
var paintings = [
    { "_id" : ObjectId("31c75"), "data" : "0,0,0,0" },
    { "_id" : ObjectId("deadb"), "data" : "1,3,0,255" }
];
```

Which is loaded into the controller by a factory:

```
app.factory('paintings', ['$http', function($http) {
    var o = {
        paintings: []
    };
    o.getAll = function() {
        return $http.get('/paintings')
            .success(function(data) {
                angular.copy(data, o.paintings);
            });
    }
    return o;
}]);
```

I'm wanting to loop through each entry and construct a `<canvas>` element, then pass that `<canvas>` element to another object (`Grid`) with `data` as an argument, which creates context and draws on that `<canvas>` based on the data.
 Simple, right? Unfortunately, I'm at a loss for how to do so and do not have the language with which to ask a more poignant question.
I think problems exist in the fact that I am using inline-templates which aren't yet rendered.

This is generally the approach I am currently trying:

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="painting in paintings" some-directive-maybe="bindCanvas(painting._id)">
    <canvas id="{{ painting._id }}" width="800" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('PaintingCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    function($scope) {
        $scope.bindCanvas(canvasId) {
            var grid = new Grid(document.getElementById(canvasId));
            // Have fun with grid
        }
    }
]);
```

Help me, StackOverflow. You're my only hope...

Comment: Is your paintings object defined on scope like $scope.paintings ?

Comment: @RaviTeja: I believe it should be copied to $scope by the factory I included in my recent edit

Comment: I have updated my answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var paintings = [
    { "_id" : ObjectId("31c75"), "data" : "0,0,0,0" },
    { "_id" : ObjectId("deadb"), "data" : "1,3,0,255" }
];
```

paintings should be in an `array`.

```
 app.controller('PaintingCtrl', [
        '$scope',
        function($scope) {
            $scope.bindCanvas(canvasId) {
                var grid = new Grid(document.getElementById(canvasId));
                // Have fun with grid
            }
            //paintings should be on scope for ng-repeat to find it.
            // If ng-repeat does not find paintings on scope then it will create a new empty paintings object on scope
            $scope.paintings = [ 
              { _id : "31c75", data : "0,0,0,0" },
              { _id : "deadb", data : "1,3,0,255" }
             ];

        }
    ]);
```

**Update:**

I have created 2 plunkers.

First, [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/w5d4ngsOpjDDQhRemMht?p=preview)  just creates `canvas` elements with `static` `width` and `height`. Number of `canvas` elements created is based upon number of paintings in `painting.json` file.

Second, [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/LNw2sDcS5IItZrBH269d?p=preview) goes a step further and creates `canvas` elements with `dynamic` `width` and `height`. Number of `canvas` elements created is based upon number of paintings in `painting.json` file. Here `width` and `height` are based upon `data` property in `paintings.json` file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Whoops, I typed it wrong. It is an array, being loaded into $scope by a factory. I will edit my question. Should I build a directive for such a task?

Comment: Thanks! Your plunkers helped me get it!

Answer (score 0):

Following code also works for repeat chart on the same page.

```
<div ng-repeat="a in abc">
    <canvas id="pieChart{{a}}" ng-bind = "bindCanvas(a)" ></canvas>
<div>
```

Add below code in JS file

```
$scope.abc = [1,2,3];

$scope.bindCanvas = function(i) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("pieChart"+i);
    new Chart(ctx,{
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            labels: ["Tele-conference", "Projector", "Laptop", "Desktop", "Coffee-machine"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "Population (millions)",
                backgroundColor: ["red", "green","blue","violet","yellow"],
                data: [200,100,300,400,150]
            }]
        },
    });
}
```